# php DOMDocument()->loadXML() not working

Tags: php, xml

I have this XML automatically produced by GPAC MP4Box.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!-- MPD file Generated with GPAC version 0.5.1-DEV-rev5223M  on 2014-05-08T02:46:28Z-->
<MPD 
    xmlns="urn:mpeg:dash:schema:mpd:2011" minBufferTime="PT1.500000S" type="dynamic" availabilityStartTime="2014-05-07T22:02:08Z" 
    timeShiftBufferDepth="PT0H0M0.00S" profiles="urn:mpeg:dash:profile:isoff-live:2011">
    <ProgramInformation 
        moreInformationURL="http://gpac.sourceforge.net">
        <Title>session.mpd generated by GPAC</Title>

    </ProgramInformation>

    <Period id="GENID_DEF" start="PT0H0M0.00S">
        <AdaptationSet segmentAlignment="true" maxWidth="352" 
                       maxHeight="288" maxFrameRate="5" par="352:288">
            <SegmentTemplate timescale="10240" media="stream$Number$.m4s" 
                             startNumber="1" duration="20480" initialization="streaminit.mp4"/>
            <Representation id="1" mimeType="video/mp4" 
                            codecs="avc1.42e014" width="352" height="288" frameRate="5" sar="1:1" startWithSAP="1" bandwidth="192548">
            </Representation>

        </AdaptationSet>
    </Period>
</MPD>
```

And

```
$x = new DOMDocument();
$x->loadXML('session.mpd');
```

Results in:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadXML(): Start tag expected, '<' not found in Entity, line: 1
```

Does any one see what is wrong?

Comment: If I recall correctly, XML must start with `<?xml`, not `<? xml`. Also no spaces for `version="1.0"`.

Comment: sorry it actually does, my editor put the spaces in

Comment: It's either one of these options: one. Your XML has errors in it, somehow, somewhere. Try running a few online parsers, see if it validates. If it does, then it's possible it might be two. You're using an older version of PHP where a bug was present where valid XML could not be parsed. What version are you running?

Comment: @Mave PHP Version 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.11

Comment: Okay, when I try to run this code myself, by referencing a file it's a no-go. But by pasting the xml directly into the `loadXML()` function, it works. I can't test more as I've run out of time, but I do hope this points you at least somewhat in the right direction.

Comment: oh that's interesting, ok I'll give it a try. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DOMDocument::loadXML`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadxml.php) expects XML source as an argument, if you are going to use file path, use [`DOMDocument::load`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.load.php)